# Cómo mostrar los datos Sí la condicíon IF es verdadera

Tags: jquery, ajax

`Mi codigo de AJAX:`

```
     $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/comprarbloqueo/ComBloLlenar_Datos?ComBloid=' + IdComBloCli,
            type: 'POST',
            data: "",
            contentType: 'json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                
                $(data).each(function (i, row) {
                Nacionalidad = row.CLI_Nacionalidad;
                vTxtPasaporte = row.CLI_Pasaporte;
                vTxtNombre = row.CLI_Nombre;
                vTxtApellidoPa = row.CLI_ApellidoPa;
                vTxtApellidoMa = row.CLI_ApellidoMa;
                vTxtTelefono = row.CLI_Telefono;
            });
             alert(Nacionalidad);
            alert(vTxtPasaporte);
            alert("Completar la condicion");

            if ($("#cboNacionalidad").val() == Nacionalidad && $("#txtPasaporte").val() == vTxtPasaporte)
            {
                alert("Entrooo");                        
                    $("#txtNombre").val(vTxtNombre); 
                    $("#txtApellidoPa").val(vTxtApellidoPa);
                    $("#txtApellidoMa").val(vTxtApellidoMa);
                    $("#txtTelefono").val(vTxtTelefono);                    
                }else{                     
                alert("Eres Cliente Nuevo");
                }                         
          },
```

Cómo obtendría los datos de BD al rellenar la Nacionalidad y Pasaporte?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día. ¿Podrías ser más específico por favor? No entiendo a qué te refieres.

Comment: Hola amigo , en el imagen mostrado tengo 6 campos,
            mi idea de hacer es al rellenar la NACIONALIDAD y PASAPORTE, 
            quiero que me muestre automaticamente los datos de los demás campos que falta rellenar
            que esta en DASE DATOS (SQL),pero siempre y cuando existe los datos
            (NACIONALIDAD y PASAPORTE ) SI NO  normal relleno asi a mano.
            "Para estaba haciendo la condificon IF pero no me esta funcionando Amigazo".

Comment: ya revisaste la consola a ver si te sale algún error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba haciendo algo como esto (Recuerda cambiar los nombres de los campos a como los tengas en la base de datos):

```
 //Recordar qie los datos se envían por POST 
$.ajax({
  url: '/comprarbloqueo/ComBloLlenar_Datos',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    nacionalidad: $("#comboNacionalidad"),
    pasaporte: $("#comboPasaporte")
  },
  success: function (data) {
    if (!data) {
      // JSON.parse convierte ese JSON en un objeto
      var objDato = JSON.parse(data);
      //Lo que sigue después de: "objDato[0]." se pone según el nombre del campo que se obtiene de la base datos 
      $('#txtNombre').val(objDato[0].Nombre);
      $('#txtApellidoPa').val(objDato[0].ApellidoPa);
      $('#txtApellidoMa').val(objDato[0].ApellidoMa);
      $('#txtTelefono').val(objDato[0].Telefono);
    }else{
      alert("Vaya! Parece que eres un cliente nuevo.");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66734/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-como-mostrar-los-datos-si-la-condicion-if-es-verd).

Answer (score 0):

> Mi idea de hacer es al rellenar la `Nacionalidad` y `Pasaporte`, quiero **que muestre automáticamente los datos de los demás campos que falta rellenar** que está en la base de datos, pero siempre y cuando estos existan. Si no es el caso, relleno a mano.

Podrías hacer un listener en el input pasaporte para realizar la petición al servidor con los datos: `nacionalidad` y `pasaporte`.

El servidor realiza la consulta con esos datos:

```
SELECT * FROM <tabla> WHERE nacionalidad = ? AND pasaporte = ? LIMIT 1
```

Pueden ocurrir dos cosas:

1. Existe un registro con dichos datos
2. No existe ningún registro

Si existe el registro obviamente retornarás ese registro y en el `success` o `done` de `jQuery#ajax` rellenas los datos. En caso contrario no se rellenará nada porque no hay datos en la respuesta.

```
$('#txtPasaporte').on('input', function(e) {
  const passport = $(this).val();
  const nationality = $('#txtNacionalidad').val();

  // enviar por AJAX al server para que se compruebe la info
  $.ajax({
    url: '....',
    data: { passport, nationality },
    type: 'POST',
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    if (!data) { return; }

    $(data).each(function (i, row) {
      $('#txtNombre').val(row.CLI_Nombre);
      $('#txtApellidoPa').val(row.CLI_ApellidoPa);
      $('#txtApellidoMa').val(row.CLI_ApellidoMa);
      $('#txtTelefono').val(row.CLI_Telefono);
    });

    // remueves el listener una vez encontrado un registro
    $(this).off('input');
  });
});
```

Comment: Esta muy bueno Amigo, tengo una consulta, al rellenar Pasaporte,
                    si me devuelve los datos esta correcto hasta aqui, lo que pasa es cuando no esta en
                    BASE DATOS (PASAPORTE) sigue me devulve los datos de los demas campos. 
                    SINO esta en Base de Datos el  (PASAPORTE) no me devolveria.

Comment: @MMarioMandzukicMarioMandzu Claro, si no hay registros en la base de datos con la nacionalidad y pasaporte, entonces la consulta debería traerte null o un array vacío, por ejemplo. Comprueba en cada caso el resultado de la consulta.

Comment: Aunque Cuando  no hay  el registro nacionalidad y pasaporte.  en base de  
datos, sigue me trae los registros. como controlaria para que no 
me trae los datos sino esta en Base Datos

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido. Es decir, ¿qué datos podría traerte de la base de datos **si no hay ningún registro que coincide con dichos parámetros,**? Esa consulta no debería devolver absolutamente nada. ¿Qué consulta haces?

Comment: TABLA Clientes:
        ClientesId   CLI_Nombre   CLI_ApellidoPa  CLI_ApellidoMa  CLI_Telefono  CLI_Pasaporte  CLI_Nacionalidad
        1               Michael     Peñaloza        Aguirre         986475212     Visa1         1
        2               Luz         Palomino        Lazo            9648872       Visa2         5

Comment: /*       Asi es mi tabla de base de datos  por ejemplo si eligo CLI_Nacionalidad = 1 Y  CLI_Pasaporte = Visa1
            me devolveria esta linea Michael     Peñaloza        Aguirre         986475212 4

Comment: @MMarioMandzukicMarioMandzu Eso es lo correcto. Ahora, si `CLI_Nacionalidad` y `CLI_Pasaporte` no corresponden a los valores pasados por consulta, lo normal es que **no se obtengan resultados de la base de datos**. ¿Podrías poner la consulta SQL que estás haciendo?

Comment: estoy saliendo con Linq igual le pongo

Comment: public List<ClienteBlo> ComBloLlenar_Datos(int ComBloid) 
 {
var comblo_nombre = from comblo in contexto.Cliente
where comblo.ClientesId == ComBloid
  select new ClienteBlo
 {
ClientesId = comblo.ClientesId,
BloqueosId = comblo.BloqueosId,
CLI_Nombre = comblo.CLI_Nombre,
CLI_ApellidoPa = comblo.CLI_ApellidoPa,
CLI_ApellidoMa = comblo.CLI_ApellidoMa,
CLI_Telefono = comblo.CLI_Telefono,
CLI_Pasaporte = comblo.CLI_Pasaporte,
CLI_Nacionalidad = comblo.CLI_Nacionalidad,
CLI_Activo = comblo.CLI_Activo,
 };
 return comblo_nombre.ToList();
               }

Comment: @MMarioMandzukicMarioMandzu Vale, veo que en el linq haces solo un where y es para `comblo.ClientesId == ComBloid` pero no haces el where también para `CLI_Nacionalidad` y `CLI_Pasaporte`.

Comment: Para CLI_Nacionalidad y CLI_Pasaporte el Where  cómo lo haría